# Slow bash tab completion

Tags: bash, auto-completion

My bash shell's tab completion is very slow, usually taking 1-2 seconds per completion. This only seems to happen when I'm using my laptop from work. Tab completion is very speedy when using my laptop from home. I've tried looking around in ~/.bashrc and /etc/bash_completion.d, but I have not found a solution as of yet.

Comment: Is it just a normally slow laptop? Are there lots of files in the folders you are auto completing?

Comment: Tim, thank you for your response. It is not normally a slow laptop. In fact, it has a 2.7GHz processor so I imagine hardware shouldn't be the issue. Also, there are usually very few files in the folders that I'm auto-completing (I'd say about a dozen or less on average).

Comment: Is `Alt + /` snappy while `Tab` is slow?

Comment: The problem randomly disappeared, otherwise I'd let you know. Thanks :)

Comment: @thatotherguy: I'm having this very problem and `Alt+/` is indeed snappy while `Tab` is slow. Where were you going with this?

Comment: @nmichaels It just narrows the problem down to the bash-completion package, and rules out the other things suggested like slow hardware and too many files.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on a Debian system recently, and found the solution on [Unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185960/6008).

It was [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash-completion/+bug/1390061), fixed by [this patch](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/189392264/bash_completion.patch).